# Sed with Python/subprocess.call: How can I make python execute this call to sed

Tags: python, regex, bash, replace, sed

The working sed I run from the shell is:

```
sed -re 's/(::\s+ni\s+=)[^=]*$/\1 512/' test.dat
```

However, I cannot get it to run with Python's subprocess.call:

I have the following:

```
infile = 'test.dat'
cmd= [
      "sed",
      "-re",
      "s/(::\s+ni\s+=)[^=]*$/\1 512/",
      infile
     ]
subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=open('out_test.dat','w'))
```

I tried many different ways but I always get a non-zero exit status.

Comment: Is it because your regex expression should contain single quotes surrounded by double quotes, i.e., `"'s/(::\s+ni\s+=)[^=]*$/\1 512/'"`?

Comment: You need to escape your slashes.

Comment: Why don't you use Python's built-in regex replace functionality?

Comment: @Bill: It doesn't have single quotes surrounded by double quotes in the shell command line.

Comment: Also, isn't `sed` writing an error message to stderr that you can see when you run the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the Python string `"s/(::\s+ni\s+=)[^=]*$/\1 512/"` contains a control-A where you wanted a backslash and a 1. Whenever you're writing regular expressions as string literals, you want to use raw strings if possible, or escape the backslashes if not. So, just change that line to:

```
r"s/(::\s+ni\s+=)[^=]*$/\1 512/",
```